# data does not save to the database Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I am having a problem while persisting the data in a relationship, I am using spring boot .. the data does not save on the base and no error appears in the log

I'll show you my relationship classes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pacientes", schema = "sau", uniqueConstraints= @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"id_pessoa", "cns"}))
public class Pacientes implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5776384003601026304L;
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idPaciente;

    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name="id_pessoa")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Pessoas pessoa;


    @Column(name = "id_responsavel_familiar")
    private BigDecimal responsavelFamiliar;


    @Column(name = "nomeResponsavel")
    private String nomeResponsavel;


    @Column(name = "cpfResponsavel")
    private String cpfResponsavel;


    @Column(name = "cnsResponsavel")
    private String cnsResponsavel;

    @Column(name = "cns")
    private String cns;


    @Column(name = "flagAlergico")
    private Integer flagAlergico;

    @Column(name = "vacinacao")
    private Integer vacinacao;


    @Column(name = "observacoesAlergias")
    private String observacoesAlergias;


    @Column(name = "microarea")
    private String microarea;


    @Column(name = "idDomicilio")
    private Long idDomicilio;


    @JoinColumn(name="id_orientacao_sexual")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private OrientacoesSexuais orientacaoSexual;


    @JoinColumn(name="id_identidade_genero")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private IdentidadesGenero identidadeGenero;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "flag_ativo", columnDefinition="int default '1'")
    private int flagAtivo;


    @JoinColumn(name="id_area")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Areas area;


    @JoinColumn(name="id_familia")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Familias familia;


    public Pacientes() {
    }
```

// gets and sets

class Pessoas

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pessoas", schema = "glb")
public class Pessoas implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4042023941980758267L;
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idPessoa;

    @Column(name = "data_nascimento")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataNascimento;

    @Column(name = "foto")
    private String foto;

    @Column(name = "inscricao_estadual")
    private String inscricaoEstadual;

    @Column(name = "inscricao_municipal")
    private String inscricaoMunicipal;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "nome_mae")
    private String nomeMae;

    @Column(name = "nome_pai")
    private String nomePai;

    @Column(name = "nome_social")
    private String nomeSocial;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "tipo_pessoa", columnDefinition=" char default 'O'")
    private String tipoPessoa;

    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_entidade")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Entidades entidade;

    public Pessoas() {
    }
```

// gets and sets

class PessoasEnderecos

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pessoas_enderecos" ,schema="glb")
public class PessoasEnderecos implements Serializable  {



    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2560542418318988673L;
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idPessoaEndereco;

    @Column(name = "bloco")
    private String bloco;

    @Column(name = "cep")
    private String cep;

    @Column(name = "complemento")
    private String complemento;

    @Column(name = "numero")
    private String numero;

    @JoinColumn(name="id_bairro")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Bairros bairros;

    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name="id_entidade")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Entidades entidade;

    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name="id_logradouro")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Logradouros  logradouro;

    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name="id_municipio")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Municipios municipio;

    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name="id_pais")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Paises pais;

    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name="id_pessoa")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Pessoas pessoa;

    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name="id_uf")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Ufs uf;



    public PessoasEnderecos() {
    }
```

//gets and sets

and its my methood to persist de object 
im getting an json object from client and passing to this method .

example of json that i gettin

```
{
    "pessoa": {
        "nome": "daaaaa",
        "nomeSocial": "aaaaaa",
        "tipoPessoa": "J",
        "pessoasEnderecos": {
            "municipio": {
                "idMunicipio": "1"
            },
            "pais": {
                "idPais": "5"
            }
        },
        "nomeMae": "aaaaaaaaa",
        "entidade": {
            "idEntidade": "1"
        }
    },
    "cns": "aaaaa",
    "cnsResponsavel": "aaaaaa",
    "cpfResponsavel": "aaaaaa",
    "nomeResponsavel": "aaaaaaaa"
}
```

@

```
RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/pacientes")
    public HttpStatus cadastrarPacientes(@RequestBody ObjectNode json) {
        try {

            Entidades entidades = new Entidades();
            entidades.setIdEntidade(json.get("pessoa").get("entidade").get("idEntidade").asLong());

            Pessoas pessoas = new Pessoas();
            pessoas.setNome(json.get("pessoa").get("nome").textValue());
            pessoas.setNomeSocial(json.get("pessoa").get("nomeSocial").textValue());
            pessoas.setNomeMae(json.get("pessoa").get("nomeMae").textValue());
            pessoas.setEntidade(new Entidades());
            pessoas.setEntidade(entidades);
            pessoas.setTipoPessoa(json.get("pessoa").get("tipoPessoa").textValue());

            Paises pais = new Paises();
            pais.setIdPais(json.get("pessoasEnderecos").get("pais").get("idPais").asLong());


            Ufs uf = new Ufs();
            uf.setIdUf(21l);

            Municipios municipio = new Municipios();
            municipio.setIdMunicipio(
                    Long.parseLong(json.get("pessoasEnderecos").get("municipio").get("idMunicipio").textValue()));

            Logradouros logradouro = new Logradouros();
            logradouro.setIdLogradouro(50);



            PessoasEnderecos pessoasEnderecos = new PessoasEnderecos();
            pessoasEnderecos.setCep(json.get("pessoasEnderecos").get("cep").textValue());
            pessoasEnderecos.setPessoa(new Pessoas());
            pessoasEnderecos.setPessoa(pessoas);
            pessoasEnderecos.setEntidade(new Entidades());
            pessoasEnderecos.setEntidade(entidades);
            pessoasEnderecos.setPais(new Paises());
            pessoasEnderecos.setPais(pais);
            pessoasEnderecos.setUf(new Ufs());
            pessoasEnderecos.setUf(uf);
            pessoasEnderecos.setMunicipio(new Municipios());
            pessoasEnderecos.setMunicipio(municipio);
            pessoasEnderecos.setLogradouro(new Logradouros());
            pessoasEnderecos.setLogradouro(logradouro);


            Pacientes pac = new Pacientes();
            pac.setPessoa(new Pessoas());
            pac.setPessoa(pessoas);
            pac.setCns(json.get("cns").toString());
            pac.setCnsResponsavel(json.get("cnsResponsavel").toString());
            pac.setCpfResponsavel(json.get("cpfResponsavel").toString());           
            pac.setNomeResponsavel(json.get("nomeResponsavel").toString());

            pacientesService.cadastrarPacientes(pessoasEnderecos, pac );


        } catch (Exception e) {
            return HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        }

        return HttpStatus.CREATED;
    }
```

and my service....

```
@Transactional
    public void cadastrarPacientes( PessoasEnderecos pessoasEnderecos,  Pacientes pac) {
        pacRepository.saveAndFlush(pac);
--thispoint     pessoasEnderecosRepository.saveAndFlush(pessoasEnderecos);


    }
```

i try to debug and i put a breakPoint at --thispoint and in `pacRepository` 
but the breakpoint dont arrive to --thispoint

i have to say that not occured any error in log.

whats wrong with these method ?

i removed  this `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` from

```
 @NotNull
        @JoinColumn(name="id_entidade")
        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Entidades entidade;
```

and i got hes new error

```
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='não pode ser nulo', propertyPath=idPessoa, rootBeanClass=class digifred.model.global.Pessoas, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]] with root cause

javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [digifred.model.global.Pessoas] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='não pode ser nulo', propertyPath=idPessoa, rootBeanClass=class digifred.model.global.Pessoas, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]
```

Comment: Log out the exception.

Comment: can you add your file configuration?

Comment: try maybe remove try  catch (Exception e). maybe there is some error hiding there

Comment: what file of configuration ? i dont have any one because using spring boot and sprign data jpa

Comment: What "database" are you using? How are you supplying the connection string?

Comment: @oak when i remove try catch i got this log error `detached entity passed to persist: digifred.model.global.Entidades`

Comment: i using postgres database

Comment: ok. so we have some progress here. If the entity is not new the  entity needs to reattach.  ```municipio.setIdMunicipio(
                    Long.parseLong(json.get("pessoasEnderecos").get("municipio").get("idMunicipio").textValue()));``` you assume this id exist in database? If so you need to reattach(i.e merge the entity) or pull it from the database

Comment: moreover why do you create new instance and then a different one ```pac.setPessoa(new Pessoas());
            pac.setPessoa(pessoas);``` Seems like this is repeating behavoir in many different places

Comment: @oak yes i have sure that id exists in my data base

Comment: because i need to persist `Pessoas` this belows to `paciente`

Comment: so in order to use the entity with an exist id you need to merge it and to pull it by the id

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

detached entity

### The cause

Try to set manuly the id of the entity and to use this entity

### Possible solutions:

1. `merge/` the entity to the current PersistenceContext
2. `find` the entity by the id seems like more correct in this case

Assuming the primary key of Municipios is `long` then

`@PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;
  ..
  ..
  ..
  Long  id  = Long.parseLong(json.get("pessoasEnderecos").get("municipio")‌​.get("idMunicipio").‌​textValue())
  Municipios municipios = em.find(Municipios.class, id);`